# Error in Passing Jquery variable to a php session variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

This question might seem a duplicate and There are many posts on how to pass jquery variables to php. Tried all of them none worked for me.

Here is what all I did.

From Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
       url: '/test.php',
       data: {"name":name,"phone":phone},
       type: 'post',
       success:function(data){
           console.log("Succses"); 
       }
    });
```

In test.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['phone']=$_POST['phone'];
```

There is nothing complex in this code. It is so simple and am seeing the "Success" message on the console. When am trying to echo this sssion variable in another page, this is shown empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Session on your local page will not exist until you reload the page because the session is controlled on the server-side.

Comment: Did you call session_start?

Comment: still doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

Please use `session_start()` on the first line of your PHP code to make the session works for you for that page.

You might have following problems

- Might be missing `session_start()`
- You might getting blank values on `$_POST`

Do the debug for ajax call and don't forget to check `print_r($_POST)` has values in success or not.

Comment: modifid with  session_start(); still no luck

Comment: Try with change `POST` instead of `post` and make sure that you're getting data in `$_POST`

Comment: console.log(data) is returning empty. still confused why php is not returning data

Comment: is your url is right ? what `print_r($_POST)` this gives ?

Comment: So everything is ok for you now ?

Comment: data array is showing up data. but when used in a different page, the session variables are seen empty

Comment: Try to use `session_start()` on every page where you're using session variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125512/discussion-between-loading-and-user168983).